# Using COM dll library from C++ DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll, com, dllimport

I'm creating my own c++ dll. I would like to be able to use my COM lib from that C++ DLL.
This is how I'm using my COM DLL from normal exe:

```
#import "MyLib.tlb"
using namespace MyLib;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    ITestClassPtr testClass(__uuidof(TestClass));
    long result = testClass->Add(20, 34);
    std::cout << result;
    std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    CoUninitialize();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And it is working great.

**How should I use that COM library (MyLib) from DLL file? How and where to initialize it? Where to keep pointer to ITestClassPtr?**

I tried this but it is crashing:

```
#import "MyLib.tlb"
using namespace MyLib;
ITestClassPtr testClass;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CoInitialize(NULL);
        testClass = new ITestClassPtr(__uuidof(TestClass));
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        CoUninitialize();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        CoInitialize(NULL);
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        CoUninitialize();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: `COM` objects are created with `CoCreateInstance` (or `CreateInstance` on a `COM` smart pointer. You generally don't `new` them up.

Comment: Related: Just for your info, that `main()` sample isn't "working great". That code tears down COM *before* the release of that smart pointer (which invokes the object's `Release()`, etc.). If that object performs *anything* with COM-initialized-required APIs (ex: `SysAllocString`, etc) and cleans them up on release (ex: `SysFreeString()`, it will crash before `main()` ends.

Comment: The things you can do in your DllMain() entrypoint are very restricted.  The Windows loader takes a lock to ensure the entrypoint calls are strictly serialized, the infamous "loader lock".  Which for one means that you cannot load any other DLLs.  So both CoInitializeEx() and CoCreateInstance() are illegal in DllMain().  You will need to export a function.

Comment: @WhozCraig How to fix it? I couldn't find much infor on the internet. And this is first thing that is working somehow.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you maybe show me how to do it? Should I create 2 function DLLInitialize and DLLUninitialize that should be called by hosing application? What to put in those functions? Code snippet would be very appreciated. I was looking for answer for long time and found nothing